# stringify not working for date in mm/dd/yyyy format while passing through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I am using json to get info from database. but while passing date it is throwing bad request. Below is my code.

```
var json = {
    "retailerId": retailerId,
    "retailerStatus": retailerStatus,
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "ssn": ssn,
    "drvLicense": drLicenseNum,
    "dob": dob
};
alert(json);
$.ajax({
    url: "search",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    success: function (
    data) {
        $("#spinner").hide();
        loadResultTable(data);
        $("#resultTableDiv").show();
    },
    error: function () {
        $("#spinner").hide();
        alert("Error Occurred while searching owner");
    }
});
```

My date format is in the input as mm/dd/yyyy like 12/10/2013

The control is not going to the spring controller, but if I remove date and put ssn, retaier id then it is going to controller.

Could you please help me?

Comment: does the data format is same in database?

Comment: No, in server side we are transferming to yyyyMMdd and in database it is in encrypted format, so we are encrypting in sever side. I want to pass the date in mm/dd/yyyy or simple ddmmyyyy format, but it is not going to controller

Comment: have you tried to print_r() your POST request?

Comment: The request is not moving to controller class

Comment: is your url:'search' is correct only? try to change it, like adding the file extension or try using the fullpath. hope it helps

Comment: If I don't select dob and put other field the control is going to controller class. So the problem is with the date only

Answer (score 1):

you can write your post string like this
 and you wont need to stringify it.

```
var dataToPost = "{ retailerId:'" + retailerId+ "', retailerStatus:" + retailerStatus+ "}";
//add the rest of the variables

$.ajax({
    url: "search",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: dataToPost,
    success: function (
    data) {
        $("#spinner").hide();
        loadResultTable(data);
        $("#resultTableDiv").show();
    },
    error: function () {
        $("#spinner").hide();
        alert("Error Occurred while searching owner");
    }
});
```

Comment: there is no luck if I add dataPost it is not going to the controller. Even if I remove the dob also it is not working. In controller it will convert to Model.

I am getting the below error
  `Status Code:400 Bad Request { dob:'02/12/2014', retailerStatus:}
Response Headersview source`

Comment: The solution worked for me after I added double quotes around field names and values to make it a valid json. Example: `var dataToPost ='{"retailerId":"' + retailerId +'"}';`